# 'Each' can be used the same way?

Tags: sentence-usage

If 'two eggs each roll' means 'two eggs roll,' then 'two eggs roll on two desk each' can mean 'two eggs roll on two desk'?
I know it can mean 'each egg rolls on two desk' or 'two eggs roll on each desk,' but it also can just mean 'two eggs roll on two desk' as 'two eggs each roll' mean 'two eggs roll'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the position of "each" in a sentence changes the meaning.

"Two eggs roll on two desks each" means that "each egg rolls on two desks", because "each" comes after "two desks".

"Two eggs roll on each desk" means that "each desk has two eggs rolling on it" because "each" comes right before "desk".

"Two eggs each roll" means "each of the two eggs rolls" because "each" comes between the subject "two eggs" and the verb, "roll".